# How can I create a trigger in MySql to automatically update a column based on another table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

### EXAMPLE

Table 1 has 2 fields: (1) Company's Code & (2) Supplier's Code
Table 2 also has 2 fields: (1) Company's Code & (2) Supplier's Code

Table 1 is a 'directory' which matches the supplier's code to our company's code respectively. 
For table 2, the supplier's code will be input by a person. The trigger will then search table 1 and find the matching company's code and automatically fill up the column.

I created a trigger, but I realized my table became locked and I cannot add any data. An error appears: **Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `mydb`.`whole_rolls_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `whole_rolls` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE whole_rolls
INNER JOIN reference_table on whole_rolls.supplierFoilCode = reference_table.supplierFoilCode
SET whole_rolls.parentFoilCode = reference_table.parentFoilCode;
END
```

So how can I achieve what i'm trying to do?

---

SAMPLE DATA

Table 1 (reference_table)

```
 Parent Foil Code  Supplier Foil Code
    SLV1-AEEGLB            12345
    SLV2-AEEGLB            12346
    SLV3-AEEGLB            12347
    SLV4-AEEGLB            12348
    SLV5-AEEGLB            12349
```

Table 2 (whole_rolls)

```
Parent Foil Code  Supplier Foil Code
  [Automatic]           12348
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Edited the question and added them as tables

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say based off table1 you want to update table2.

your trigger is running on the insert of table2 and trying to update table2.

I think you want something similar to below

```
UPDATE reference_table
set reference_table.parentFoilCode = NEW.parentFoilCode
WHERE reference_table.supplierFoilCode = NEW.supplierFoilCode
```

Instead of the query that you are using which is going to cause that error to raise up.

or you are going to have to change where you are pointing your trigger. your trigger would have to be referencing the reference table instead of the whole_rolls table.

change

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `mydb`.`whole_rolls_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `whole_rolls` FOR EACH ROW
```

to

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `mydb`.`reference_table_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `reference_table` FOR EACH ROW
```

EDIT:

After your clarifying comments what you want is not an after insert, but a before insert

you will also have to the below. this is an example of what I think you would need your code may vary a little

you basically grab the parent foil code from the reference table and store it in a variable then you change the NEW data values(which is the record you are inserting) for the parent foil code to be what you wanted from the lookup table.

```
SELECT @parentFoilCode := parentFoilCode 
FROM reference_Table where 
supplierFoilCode = NEW.supplierFoilCode

SET NEW.supplierFoilCode = @parentFoilCode
```

Comment: I do not want to update reference_table. The reference_table is similar to the table of contents in a book. When I say I want to go to read about a certain topic, the table of contents will tell me what page to go to.

Comment: So what I want to achieve is: if I input in the supplier's code column in table 2, it will automatically search table 1 for that supplier's code and give me it's corresponding parent foil code.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but what I understand from "after insert" is that after I input the values into table 2, it will trigger. If it's "before insert" won't the trigger activate before I even input the values? If yes, then there's no data for it to even search in the reference table.

Comment: Also the code you suggested did not seem to work when I put it in before insert trigger